# Is it possible to install elementaryOS on ryzen 5600x (+nvdia gpu)

Tags: elementary-project, ryzen

Hello guys before diving into uknown space, is anybody got dome experience with elementary on Ryzen 5600x CPU ?

Thanks:-)

Comment: The answer is 'probably'. You can test it yourself without installing anything. Just use a live USB and if it works there it'll work after you install it.